# Improper output in SSH session on OSX using FreeSSHd on Windows with cygwin bash/sh shell

Tags: windows, ssh, bash, cygwin, freesshd

I am testing out running an SSH server on a local Windows VM.

I have installed FreeSSHd and set the command shell to "c:\cygwin\bin\sh --login -i" (bash as well) with "Use new console engine" unchecked.  (When it was enabled no output would show through the ssh connection anyway)

The shell seems to work, but when connecting from my OS-X terminal using ssh all of the shell results comes out ill formatted.

```
      $ ls -al
          total 17
                  drwxr-xr-x+ 1 SYSTEM        Administrators 4096 Feb  2 01:00 .
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 Administrator Administrators    0 Feb  2 01:01 ..
                                                               -rw-------  1 SYSTEM        Administrators  128 Feb  2 01:30 .bash_history
                                                         -rwxr-xr-x  1 SYSTEM        Administrators 1150 Feb  2 00:55 .bash_profile
                                                   -rwxr-xr-x  1 SYSTEM        Administrators 3754 Feb  2 00:55 .bashrc
                                       -rwxr-xr-x  1 SYSTEM        Administrators 1461 Feb  2 00:55 .inputrc
```

Any ideas on why this is happening, how I can fix this?

Comment: Try `stty onlcr` - translate newline to carriage-return+newline.

Comment: I am not on OSX anymore, so I won't be able to test any additional responses

Answer (score 1):

Almost sounds like the two ends aren't passing terminal parameters properly.

Here are a few things to try.  Set your terminal window to 80x24.  This is the historical standard (TN3270) size of a terminal window.  And/or reset the expectations on the size of the terminal on the remote side.  There are various ways to accomplish this, such as `eval $(resize)` or `stty cols X; stty rows Y` (where X and Y is the width and height of your terminal)

Comment: I am not sure what the eval resize is supposed to do, but nothing changes, as for the stty, I get this: `stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device`